# Dreamweaver Throwing Errors About "Access to ...\dwsync.xml was denied"

Tags: ftp, adobe, dreamweaver

I'm using Adobe Dreamweaver CS4 on two systems - one running Windows Vista and the other running Windows7.  I've got a client's web site (several thousand files) manually mirrored between the two systems.

On the Win7 machine, when putting files to the server, I get lots of "Access to ...\dwsync.xml was denied" errors.  The Dreamweaver site configuration is identical on both machines, as are the Windows filesystem settings (permissions, security, etc.)  I've made sure all files, directories, and subdirectories are writable.  Other than the OS, I don't see any difference in the setup, yet I continue to get these errors.

I did an extensive Google search, but came up with only a few results.  Most of them were several years old, did not explain the cause of the error, and offered no solutions that worked (it was basically "make sure nothing is read-only".

Does anyone have any ideas on what's going on here?  Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue with Dreamweaver CS5 and Windows 7. I solved it by shutting off the "User Account Control"

Control Panel > User Accounts > Change User Account Control Settings. Just set it to "Never notify". You'll have to restart the computer.

Best of luck!